# Application Match Function how to copy paste data

Tags: excel, vba

Using Application.Match Function but unable to know how to paste the `Col"M"` data into `Col"P"` after the Matching the `Col"O"` and `Col"L"`.

When run the Current function it gives the count of match.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

```
Dim k As Integer

For k = 2 To 9
ws2.Cells(k, 16).Value = Application.Match(ws2.Cells(k, 15).Value, ws2.Range("L2:L9"), 0)


Next k
```

I have edited the code with the columns and in which column the result is required. But unable to make changes I really appreciate your help that you make this function. I added some comments may it can help.

```
' Sheet2 Col"C" with ID's
With ws2
   Dim lastRow As Long
   lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

   Dim originalData() As Variant
   originalData = .Range("C2:C" & lastRow).Value
End With

' Sheet2 Col"C" with ID's
With ws3
   Dim lastRow2 As Long
   lastRow2 = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
   Dim newData() As Variant
   newData = .Range("C2:C" & lastRow2).Value
End With


Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(newData, 1) To UBound(newData, 1)
    Dim j As Long
    
    For j = LBound(originalData, 1) To UBound(originalData, 2)
        If newData(i, 1) = originalData(j, 1) Then
            newData(i, 2) = originalData(j, 2)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next

'Sheet2 Col"K" where Sheet3 Col"E" data will be pasted
ws2.Range("K2:K" & lastRow).Value = newData
```

Comment: Are the values in Col L unique?

Comment: No Unique Values are in Sheet2 Col"C" and Sheet3 Col"C" that needs to match then Take the data from Sheet3 Col"G" and Paste into Sheet2 Col"K".

Comment: I was asking about your screenshot - I know it's sample data but just trying to get what are the constraints for what you're doing...

Comment: In Screen Shot i am trying to paste the Col"M" data into col"P" after matching the Col"L" and Col"O".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always should test if the `Match` succeeded, using `IsError`.

Then use `Cells`:

```
Dim k As Long

For k = 2 To 9
    Dim m As Variant
    m = Application.Match(ws2.Cells(k, 15).Value, ws2.Range("L2:L9"), 0)

    If Not IsError(m) Then
         ws2.Cells(k, 16).Value = ws2.Range("M2:M9").Cells(m)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank you very much i was just missing this and unable to elaborate. Thanks @BigBen but its is slow it takes approx. 20 seconds to find all match is there any faster way. I have more then 10 thousands of data to match.

Answer (score 2):

A scripting dictionary which maps "keys" to "values" is typically the fastest approach when you need to perform a lot of lookups.  It's a bit more code to write but should be quick.

```vb
Sub DoLookup()

    Dim arrKeys, arrValues, wsData As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim map As Object, rngSearch As Range, rngResults As Range, k, v, n As Long
    
    Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3") 'sheet with the lookup table
    Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2") 'sheet to be populated
    
    arrKeys = wsData.Range("C2:C" & LastRow(wsData, "C")).Value   'keys in the lookup table
    arrValues = wsData.Range("G2:G" & LastRow(wsData, "C")).Value 'values in the lookup table

    Set map = MapValues(arrKeys, arrValues)                      'get a map of Keys->Values
    
    Set rngSearch = wsDest.Range("C2:C" & LastRow(wsDest, "c"))  'keys to look up
    Set rngResults = rngSearch.EntireRow.Columns("K")            'results go here
    
    arrKeys = rngSearch.Value     'keys to look up
    arrValues = rngResults.Value  'array to populate with results
    
    For n = 1 To UBound(arrKeys)  'loop over keys to look up
        v = ""  'or whatever you want to see if no match
        k = arrKeys(n, 1)
        If map.exists(k) Then v = map(k)
        arrValues(n, 1) = v
    Next n
    
    rngResults.Value = arrValues 'populate the results array back to the sheet

End Sub

'Return a Scripting Dictionary linking "keys" to "values"
' Note - assumes same-size single-column inputs, and that keys are unique,
'     otherwise you just map to the *last* value for any given key
Function MapValues(arrKeys, arrValues)
    Dim n, dict As Object, k
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For n = 1 To UBound(arrKeys, 1)
        k = CStr(arrKeys(n, 1)) 'string keys are faster to add?
        If Len(k) > 0 Then dict(k) = arrValues(n, 1)
    Next n
    Set MapValues = dict
End Function

'utility function
Function LastRow(ws As Worksheet, col As String) As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row
End Function
```

In my test workbook this was able to perform 10k lookups against a table of 10k rows in <0.1 sec.

Comment: sorry for being late i was off from duty. I am receicing an error that is compile error `Expected Array` on line `arrKeys = wsData.Range("D2:D" & LastRow(wsData, "A")).Value   'keys in the lookup table` specifically highlighted  this `LastRow`

Comment: Did you include the `LastRow` function from my post?

Comment: Yes i included.

Comment: Do you have `Option Explicit` at the top of you code module?

Comment: No, might be this could be the problem let me check

Comment: Works fine for me.  If you included the LastRow() function then it should get called on that line, but it looks like your code is looking for an array with that name...  Did you copy the code exactly as posted?  Or did you change any of the variable declarations?

Comment: No i did not change any variable just changed the columns numbers. Let me update the function

Comment: Can you share your workbook?  Pretty difficult for me to make suggestions since I can't see your setup.

Comment: Yes i can share the workbook but cannot share it publically as it contains office material.

Comment: This is my test workbook: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nAVBgYhiNDcep9Hon3BQv7ZjUfKlTvuN/view?usp=sharing